# How to encode and set url as query string to other url in location.href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following url

`http://www.example.com/p1/val1/p1/val2`

Now I want to pass third parameter as url like '/path/to/file'

`http://www.example.com/p1/val1/p1/val2/url/?????`

How can I do that with combination of js and php?

After passing above, I would like to get value of `url` as '/path/to/file'

I am passing above link through js's location.href.

How to do that?

I am getting following error?

```
Not Found

The requested URL http://www.example.com/p1/val1/p1/val2/url//path/to/file was not found on this server.
```

Comment: @nietonfir, I see that question but then my page is throwing an error

Comment: url//path <- '//' maybe here is a problem

Comment: @greko, Yes but my url is string with `/path/to/file`

Comment: why didn't use traditional query string???

Answer (score 0):

why didn't use traditional query string?

```
http://www.example.com?p1[]=val1&p1[]=val2&url=<?php echo urlencode('/path/to/file'); ?>
```

Comment: A url I specified is following MVC structure and I have to follow in that way

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you process your urls this way:

```
http://www.example.com/p1/val1/p2/val2/...
```

gets transformed into:

```
http://www.example.com?p1=val1&p2=val2&...
```

So, your poblem is that your `url` parameter receives, as value, either '' or just 'path'.

You could try this, with javascript

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/p1/val/p1/val2';
var path = '/path/to/file';
var finalUrl = url + '/url/' + encodeURIComponent(path);
```

Comment: No. My url does not transforms in to `http://www.example.com?p1=val1&p2=val2&...`

Comment: Even so, have you tried encoding the URL this way?